# How can I sum some of the values in an object array using reduce (underscore?)

Tags: mapreduce, underscore.js

I have the following JSON structure.

```
var fooArray =
    [{ name: 'firstValue',
     price1: 20,
     price2: 11
    },
    {  name: 'secondValue',
     price1: 54,
     price2: 13
    },
    {  name: 'thirdValue',
     price1: 3,
     price2: 6
    }]
```

How can I sum up the values in the object array?  (other than using a `for` loop)

```
{price1: 77,
 price2: 28}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce over the array with a function that sums the properties:

```
_.reduce(fooArray, function (accum, x) {
    return { 
        price1: x.price1 + accum.price1, 
        price2: x.price2 + accum.price2
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to @MatthewMcveigh's answer, but the resulting object does not have a spurious `name` property:

```
_.reduce(fooArray, function (accum, x) {
    return { 
        price1: x.price1 + accum.price1, 
        price2: x.price2 + accum.price2
    };
}, {price1: 0, price2: 0});
```